# what is the degree of freedom of a pair of gear wheels?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanisms

Two gear wheels A and B are touching each other and they can rotate about fixed points P and Q respectively. how to calculate the degree of freedom of the system by using gubbler's equation?

Answer (score 1):

The gear is just  two otherwise independent items linked together. What  you do is calculate the freedom as you would without  the gear and then eliminate one from the other of the gearpairs to account for the gear forcing the other object. So if your gears can just  rotate and  have only one degree of fredom then the system of 2 gears  has freedom of 1.

It is not generally a good idea to think this way  unless you idealize the gear quite much. A real gear sytem does have backlash.